# цель: ввести вручную значения словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

в словарь необходимо ввести значения. В данном примере записывает только последние введенные значения, а нужно все...

```
for i in range(2):
    dict_1 = {}
value = input("Enter value: ")
key = input("Enter key: ")
dict_1.update({key: value})
    i = i + 1
print(dict_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```py
dict_1 = {}  # Создаём словарь

for i in range(2):  # Повторяем 2 раза
    value = input("Enter value: ")
    key = input("Enter key: ")
    dict_1[key] = value  # Записываем значения

print(dict_1)
```

Comment: спасибо! то что надо, заработало!

Comment: @DmKK примите ответ, если он вам помог (серая галочка слева).